# Which scriptures describe the importance of Sarva-pitru Amavasya or Mahalaya Amavasya?

Tags: puranas, rituals, pitru, amavasya

Which scriptures mention the significance of [Sarva-pitru Amavasya](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/nagpur/Sarvapitri-Amavasya-A-day-devoted-to-ancestors/articleshow/10134441.cms) or Mahalaya Amavasya and the day (or amavasya) of the year this needs to be observed?

I'm looking for verses from scriptures and their translation.